# С# проблема. Компилятор выеживается на символы

Tags: c#, функциональное-программирование

Салам Алейкум, добрый вечер или что у вас там. Пишу лабораторные по своей учебной программе. Есть задание, написать прогу на вычисление значений функции у = а*х^a * e^-x/a, для каждого из заданных значений а
Код написан, но каждый раз при исправлении какой-то ошибки возникает новая. И вот я не могу понять, то ли я дурак, то ли лыжи не едут. Помогите, товарищи по несчастью и профессии. исходный код 
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvoXG.png) https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifvYe.png[image: исходный код]

УПД Добавил код, не загрузился изначально

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
 class Program 
  {
  static void Main (string[]args) 
    {
        double a, x, y;
        p.WriteLine ("Результаты расчёта");
        for (a = 1; a <= 2; a +=0.25f)
        {
            p.WriteLine(" a=" + a);
            for (x = 0; x <= 10; x += 0.25f)
            {
                y = (float)(a * Math.Pow(double x, double a) * Mat.Pow(double e, double -x/a);
                Console.WriteLine(" x= " + x + '\t' + " y= " +y);
            }
            Console.Readkey();
        }
```

Comment: у вас проблема с кодом - вот и показывайте код.

Comment: Сейчас мы должны все вместе угадать какие ошибки вы уже исправили и какие новые вылезли?

Comment: Код надо добавлять текстом, а не картинкой.

Comment: И прочитайте [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), пожалуйста.

Comment: @IgorR. код который на картинке текстом мне сайт не даёт этот загрузить, какое-то там редактирование ему не нравится

Comment: @Conor McGregor вероятно, на то есть причины.

Comment: Ctrl+K нажми. Написано же.

Comment: @Qwertiy получилось загрузить код. Убрал п.врайтлайн, буква "е", да, это экспонента, её нужно прописать в код, а как?

Comment: @ConorMcGregor, `Math.Exp`.

Comment: @Qwertiy (Matx.Exp,  -x/a); вот так что ли? Мне надо e в степени -х/а

Comment: Нет, не так. Открой уже учебник наконец? Или хотя бы примеры на msdn.

Comment: @Qwertiy дайте пожалуйста учебник, у меня его нет и линк на мсдн, если можно. Я чайник.

Comment: @ConorMcGregor, 1. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/178988 2. `Math.Exp msdn` или `Math.Exp C#` в гугл - получится https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.math.exp?view=netframework-4.8.

Comment: "Это классика! Это знать надо!". Как можно садится за написание программы не имея каких-либо базовых знаний...

Answer (score 2):

1. Что ещё за `p`?
2. Ты вызов функции от объявления отличаешь? Где ты такие вызовы видел?
3. Нет у тебя `е`. И вообще, используй экспоненту `Math.Exp` и опечатку заодно поправь.
4. Скобки спарь. И не только фигурные.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/402113)

Comment: @Vadizar, почему не является?